# Type confusion in Haskell: Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘Integer’

Tags: haskell

I try to use the Fibonacci array to get the golden ratio, here I define a function to get the next Fibonacci pair

```hs
fibstep :: (Num a) => (a,a) -> (a,a)
fibstep (u,v) = (v,u + v)
```

Then try to use a lambda function to get the golden ratio

```hs
golden_ratio :: (Fractional a) => Integer -> [a] 
golden_ratio n = map (\(x,y) -> x/y) (take n (iterate fibstep (0,1)))
```

But it raises the following error:

```
Recursions.hs:68:44: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘Integer’
    • In the first argument of ‘take’, namely ‘n’
      In the second argument of ‘map’, namely
        ‘(take n (iterate fibstep (0, 1)))’
      In the expression:
        map (\ (x, y) -> x / y) (take n (iterate fibstep (0, 1)))
   |
68 | golden_ratio n = map (\(x,y) -> x/y) (take n (iterate fibstep (0,1)))
   |                                            ^
Failed, no modules loaded
```

When I change `Integer` to `Int`, it works well, can someone explain it.

```hs
golden_ratio :: (Fractional a) => Int -> [a]
golden_ratio n = map (\(x,y) -> x/y) (take n (iterate fibstep (0,1)))
```

Answer (score 7):

The function `take` requires an `Int` as its first argument, but you are giving it an `Integer`.

Note that `Int` and `Integer` are different types. The former, `Int`, is for finite "machine" integers which are usually 64 bits on modern machines. The latter, `Integer`, is for arbitrary precision integers which can take as much memory as necessary.